# Paste text containing an apostrophe

Tags: excel, vba, apostrophe

I am trying to paste a **fixed** part of text to a **variable** part of text.

In my fixed part of text, a number of apostrophes appear. I get an error.

This is the part of the code that contains the apostrophes:

```
For j = 1 To nrOfItems
For i = 1 To nrOfLanguages

Set c1 = Nothing
Set c2 = Nothing
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("INPUT IMAGE WITH MOUSEOVER").Cells(j + 2, i * 2).Value) Then
        Set c1 = Sheets("INPUT IMAGE WITH MOUSEOVER").Cells(j + 2, (i * 2) + 1)
        Set c2 = Sheets("INPUT IMAGE WITH MOUSEOVER").Cells(j + 2, i * 2)
    
        code = code + "if(GETVALUE(""SD1TAAL"") ==" + _
        CStr(Sheets("INPUT WITH MOUSEOVER").Cells(1, i * 2).Value) + ")" + _
        "{ my $image =  '<img src=" ' . GRAPHICSPATH() . ' " + _
        fnConvert2HTML (c1) + _
        ".png "/>' ; my $toolTip =' " + _
        fnConvert2HTML (c2) + _
        "'; return TOOLTIP($image, $toolTip); } "
    End If

Next i
    Sheets("OUTPUT_IMAGE_WITH_MOUSEOVER").Cells(j, 1).Value = begincode + code + endcode
    code = ""
Next j
```

Things are going wrong from `' . GRAPHICSPATH() .` onward.

How can I replace the apostrophes?

Comment: You are concatenating your string with `+`?

Comment: You need to double up quotes inside strings for VBA to read them properly. The apostrophes are not a problem. And a better way to concatenate values would be the ampersand. Get in that habbit as VBA will try to convert concatenating numbers into an mathematical expression.

Comment: Can you write what your string needs to look like? I'm not entirely sure which quotes to escape here

Answer (score 1):

No need to specifically escape any apostrophe, if this is inside of a string delimited by double quotes. It is enough to escape the inside double quotes by doubling them:

Please, try the last string being built like this:

```
"{ my $image =  '<img src="" ' . GRAPHICSPATH() . ' " + _
        fnConvert2HTML(c1) + _
        ".png ""/>' ; my $toolTip =' " + _
        fnConvert2HTML(c2) + _
        "'; return TOOLTIP($image, $toolTip); } "
```

Otherwise, VBA understands that everything after `src="` is a comment...
And, also, try avoiding to use `+` for concatenation and make a habit to use `&` instead of it.

Comment: @MG92 Technically, VBA is smart enough that it will treat `+` as concatenation if **both** items are strings, but it's very bad practice.  If one of them is a number, and the other is a numeric string - for example `1+"2"` - then it will convert them both to numbers and sum them.  If one is a number, and the other is a **non**-numeric string - such as `1+"X"` - then it will throw an error.

Comment: @Chronocidal: Fully agreed. I made such a recommendation, too. What  I do not understand is the tagged user name, who did not express any opinion (here)... Should he delete his comment in the meantime...?

Comment: Yes, it looks like he deleted his comment when you updated your answer to address it.

Comment: @Chronocidal: I did not see any other comment. There were some seconds between the moment I firstly post the answer and I felt the need to also emphasize the idea of concatenation caracter to be changed. But it is good that more of us think in the same way...